# Mouse Hover on Small image, will PanZoom the Bigger Image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do this via jQuery.

I want to create a function that there's a 2 image on my page.

```
<div class="big-img">
<img src="/big.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="small-img">
<img src="/small.jpg" />
</div>

<script>
  $('.small-img')
.on('mousemove', function(e){
  $('.big-img').css({'transform-origin': ((e.pageX - $('.small-img').offset().left) / $('.big-img').width()) * 100 + '% ' + ((e.pageY - $('.big-img').offset().top) / $('.big-img').height()) * 100 +'%'});
})
</script>
```

Take note that when you hover your mouse on the small image, it will automatically move the big image (really huge image that overflow the screen).

Example of what i want: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bQgPOR

But instead of just having 1 image, i want it to have 2 image, one small one big

Comment: This is my update: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bQgPOR

The remaining issue is, it's not getting the full photo of the big image.

I mean, even if my hover on small image was on the edge of the rod, it still not getting the last part of the big image :(

Comment: I am not clear about your question. Do you want to magnify the image?